# Call a function whenever the viewport size is changed by user

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an event listener like this:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", console.log("You just resized the browser window."));
```

But it only fires once when page is loaded, and never fires again no matter how I resize the window in whatever way. Why?

I've also tried jQuery:

```
$(window).on("resize", console.log("You just resized the browser window."));
```

and

```
$(window).resize(console.log("You just resized the browser window."));
```

They didn't work either. The three are essentially all the same.

Comment: If you open your console and paste in this code right now, would it work? Mine doesn't. I've tried on different pages, and also tried on a blank html + black js. Never worked.

Comment: The second argument to `addEventListener`, `on` and `resize` should be a **function reference**. You are pass the return value of `console.log` which is `undefined`

Comment: FYI `.addEventListener('resize', function() { console.log('OMG, now it works') })`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: OMG, now it works!!! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing `console.log` instead of passing a reference to the call for the event listener to fire.

This will work:

```
notify = function() { console.log("You just resized the browser window.")}
window.addEventListener("resize", notify)
```